# Can someone help me to decipher this seal? (Characters identified: 君子愛人以德)

Tags: character-identification, seal, calligraphy

Can someone help me to decipher this seal?

[image]

---

**Edit:**

On the side carving I could read the date (辛未十二月 xīn wèi shí èr yuè: 12 1931/1991). What is the name of the carver?

[image]

Comment: 君子愛人以德 Meaning a decent person loves others with good virtue..

Comment: You need to put **a lot** more effort in your questions - they’re very poor quality as they stand now. (1) Always show us what characters you’ve deciphered already, (2) format your questions so they’re neat, (3) add all the information for the question in one go; don’t withhold some details then add them as an answer later, answers are not for question details; (4) don’t add answers when you’re making comments to other people; answers are  not for comments.

Comment: Edited part: 孙三锡刻

Answer (score 0):

君子 (gentleman, decent person) 愛人 (Loves other person) 以德 (with proper virtues.)

[image]